# Path appended but python does not find module

Tags: python, linux

I have the following structure:

```
~/git/
~/git/folder1
~/git/folder2
```

in ~/git/folder1 I have main.py, which imports doing the following:

```
import folder2.future_data as future_data
```

which throws the following error:

```
import folder2.future_data as f_d
ImportError: No module named folder2.future_data
```

Despite my `$PATH` containing

```
user@mac-upload:~$ echo $PATH
/home/user/anaconda2/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/local/games:/usr/games:/home/user/git/folder2
```

Why am I unable to import from folder2 despite it being in my path?

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try putting an empty `__init__.py` file in each directory (~/git, ~/git/folder1, and ~/git/folder2). Then do `export PYTHONPATH=${HOME}/git:$PYTHONPATH` (assuming bash shell).

This will also allow you to just set your PYTHONPATH once at the top level and be done with it. If you add more directories (modules) that you need to import, you can just keep adding `__init__.py` files to your structure (instead of having to constantly modify your `PYTHONPATH` every time your file/directory structure changes).

Answer (score 0):

You can explicitly added the path inside the main.py script before you doing import

```
import sys
sys.path.append(r'~/git/folder2')
import future_data
```